# Problema con función div y cálculo de billetes

Tags: c++

El problema que tengo está en el cálculo de los billetes, tengo dificultad para trabajar con la parte entera y la parte decimal obtenida con 'div' si alguien me podría ayudar sería muy gentil...

Escribir un programa que permita leer el nombre y el sueldo de los empleados de una
empresa, que calcule el numero de billetes de 100, 50, 20,10 y 5 dólares que se debe retirar
del banco para no tener que dar cambio a ningún empleado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sueldo;
   double b2,b4,b6,b8;
   div_t b1,b3,b5,b7,b9;
   string nombre;
   
   cout<< "Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ";
   getline(cin>>ws,nombre);
   cout<<"Ingrese el sueldo del empleado: "; //valor multiplo de 5
   cin>>sueldo;
   
    if(sueldo%5==0){
        b1<-div(sueldo/100);
        b2<-(b1.rem*100);
        b3=div(b2/50);
        b4=(b3.rem*100);
        b5=div(b4/20);
        b6=(b5.rem*100);
        b7=div(b6/10);
        b8=(b7.rem*100);
        b9=div(b8/5);
        cout<<b9.rem<<endl;
        
        cout<<  nombre<<"  tiene un sueldo de  "<<sueldo<<"  y se le debe entregar  "<<b1.quot<<"  Billetes de 100  "<<b3.quot<<"  Billetes de 50  "<<b5.quot<<"  Billetes de 20  "<<b7.quot<<"  Billetes de 10  "<<b9.quot<<"  Billetes de 5  "<<endl;
       }else{
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero multiplo de 5";
       } 
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por qué dices que está mal? Tú cuéntanos qué problema tienes con ese código. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/464607/edit) tu pregunta todas las veces que necesites, para añadir la info que haga falta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis del `div` está mal planteada.
Es `div(variable1,variable2)`
Segundo. La flecha apuntando para la izquierda tampoco existe en C.
En C el signo para asignar es `=`
Por ejemplo, para el primer caso quedaría: `b1=div(sueldo,100);`

**Referencias:**
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div_t/

Ejemplo de código usando `div` y `rem`:
https://www.codigazo.com/en-c/como-obtener-residuo-division-en-c

Answer (score 1):

Tal como te comentaron, estás usando mal la [función div](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div). Las variables `b2`, `b4`, etc no son necesarias ya que el resto de división está en los structs `b1`, `b3`, etc

Propongo variables un poco más descriptivas:

```
    // Declaraciones
    div_t b_100,b_50,b_20,b_10,b_5;
    
    // ...
    
    if(sueldo%5 == 0) {
        b_100 = div(sueldo, 100);
        b_50  = div(b_100.rem, 50);
        b_20  = div(b_50.rem, 20);
        b_10  = div(b_20.rem, 10);
        b_5   = div(b_10.rem, 5);

        cout << nombre << " tiene un sueldo de " << sueldo << " y se le debe entregar: "; 
        cout << b_100.quot << " Billetes de 100 " << b_50.quot << "  Billetes de 50 "; 
        cout << b_20.quot << " Billetes de 20 " << b_10.quot << " Billetes de 10 ";
        cout << b_5.quot << " Billetes de 5 " << endl;
    }
    // ... Resto del código
```

Answer (score 1):

Te menciono los errores encontrados:

1. Está usando mal la función `div`, la forma correcta de usar es
   `div(var1,var2)`, puedes revisar el [enlace](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/09/26/funcion-div-en-c-obtener-residuo-cociente/).
2. La asignación, la forma correcta de asignar es `=` y no `<-`
3. Las operaciones que usas para asignar los valores de tus variables de billetes, es el típico ejercicio que dejan los docentes para saber cuantos billetes usar teniendo un monto inicial.

**No es un error pero si una recomendación usar nombre de variables que sean fáciles de saber que contiene.**
El código de tu código quedaría:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sueldo;
   
   div_t b100,b50,b20,b10,b5;
   string nombre;
   
   cout<< "Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ";
   getline(cin>>ws,nombre);
   cout<<"Ingrese el sueldo del empleado: "; //valor multiplo de 5
   cin>>sueldo;
   
    if(sueldo%5==0){
        b100=div(sueldo,100);
        b50=div(b100.rem,50);
        b20=div(b50.rem,20);
        b10=div(b20.rem,10);
        b5=div(b10.rem,5);
        
        
        cout<<  nombre<<"  tiene un sueldo de  "<<sueldo<<"  y se le debe entregar  "<<b100.quot<<"  Billetes de 100  "<<b50.quot<<"  Billetes de 50  "<<b20.quot<<"  Billetes de 20  "<<b10.quot<<"  Billetes de 10  "<<b5.quot<<"  Billetes de 5  "<<endl;
       }else{
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero multiplo de 5";
       } 
       return 0;
}
```

También puedes usar el operador `/` para obtener el cociente y `%` para obtener el residuo de una división sin la necesidad de usar `div` y la librería `stdlib.h`
Te dejo el ejemplo de como usar en tu ejercicio:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sueldo;
  
   int b100,b50,b20,b10,b5;
   string nombre;   
   cout<< "Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ";
   cin>>nombre;
   cout<<"Ingrese el sueldo del empleado: "; //valor multiplo de 5
   cin>>sueldo;
   
    if(sueldo%5==0){
        b100=sueldo/100;       
        b50=(sueldo%100)/50;
        
        b20=(sueldo-b100*100)%50/20;
        
        b10=(sueldo-b100*100-b50*50)%20/10;
       
        b5=(sueldo-b100*100-b50*50-b20*20)%10/5;        
        
        cout<<  nombre<<"  tiene un sueldo de  "<<sueldo<<"  y se le debe entregar  "<<b100<<"  Billetes de 100  "<<b50<<"  Billetes de 50  "<<b20<<"  Billetes de 20  "<<b10<<"  Billetes de 10  "<<b5<<"  Billetes de 5  "<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero multiplo de 5";
    } 
       return 0;
}
```